# How to add corresponding authors footnote in a two column title page elsevier

Tags: miktex, titles, two-column, templates

I wonder how to create corresponding authors footnote in a title page, in a two column format of elsevier, knowing that I use the elsevier template suggested for this journal.
I work on shareLatex.
I use the folowing code:

```
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{sloppypar}
    %% if i put  \begin{frontmatter} here I will not get the one column abstract and two column introduction at the same page
    \title{distributed systems}

\author{coco coco\corref{cor1}\fnref{1}} 
 \ead{coco.coco@gmail.com}
 \author{momo momo\corref{cor1}\fnref{2}}
 \ead{momo.momo@gmail.com}
  \cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\address[1]{university 1}
\address[2]{university 2} 

\twocolumn[ 
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse} \begin{frontmatter}

\begin{abstract}
distributed systems distributed systems distributed systems distributed systems distributed systems distributed systems distributed systems distributed systems distributed systems.

\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
distributed systems.
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}
\vspace*{7mm}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
  ]
```

I would like to get my title page like in the image:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
```

and you don't need to modify the template with:

```
\twocolumn[ 
  \begin{@twocolumnfalse} \begin{frontmatter}
```

I have just checked the documentation on http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/doc/elsdoc.pdf and according to the doc (page 2) 5p is always two column style.

Answer (score 0):

Your tex code seems fine.
I would suggest to use the *elsarticle* template.

```
\documentclass[two-column,final]{elsarticle}
```

If you use the `two-column` and `final` option, you should get the layout you want.

This template is e.g. included with the texlive-publishers package in Debian or Ubuntu or can be downloaded at [elsarticle at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle)

Comment: actually, I use the downloaded template suggested by the journal itself and \documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}